# vscode task fail when launch but succeed when manually entered in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a simple task launching a python script with parameters.
When I use it in a file it fails with the following error

```
> Executing task: C:\Users\Clement\Documents\prepa\tipe\ocaml-tsp\external_tools\show_data\show_task.py logs\TSP20-experiment4\TSP20\instance1\MCTS-Vanilla-Random-hidden_opt\all_scores.csv 1000 <

Échec du lancement du processus de terminal : A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 193).
```

However if I manually enter the task in a cmd / powershell it works well :

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19043.1466]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\Clement\Documents\prepa\tipe\ocaml-tsp>C:\Users\Clement\Documents\prepa\tipe\ocaml-tsp\external_tools\show_data\show_task.py logs\TSP20-experiment4\TSP20\instance1\MCTS-Vanilla-Random-hidden_opt\all_scores.csv 1000
file decimated
```

The task :

```json
{
            "label": "decimate and plot csv",
            "command": "external_tools/show_data/show_task.py",
            "args": ["${relativeFile}","${input:decimateFactor}"]
        }

    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "decimateFactor",
            "description": "Decimate factor :",
            "default": "1000",
            "type": "promptString"
        }
    ]
```