vscode Cannot create process, error code: 193 how can i solve this?
enter image description here
I can't use terminal in vscode
html, java script can run
python can not run
but not in vscode, python application can run
this error is only in vscode...
Whichever I run code, it doesn't run if it is python
after I install json, python path is not added when I checked the 'add path' option when I install python.
I don't use pyinstaller
what should I do?
I had uninstalled vscode, json, and python and reinstalled them
but this problem isn't solved
I have already changed default profile

potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70886254/11107541

According to this page.
This error is usually caused by one of the following reasons:

The system's PATH environment variable is not set up correctly.
The terminal's default shell is not configured properly.
The terminal's default shell is not compatible with the command
being run.

So, you need to check your System's Path environment variables. Ensure that the directory containing the executable file for the command being run is included in the list.
You could also try to change your default terminal in the settings:

